# too many include in my program

Tags: c++, scope, header

so here the problem i have 13 include files in my program (and i am willing to include more!) but the problem is that the compiler is ignoring the last include and i can say so because i switched between two of them and the error will be always for the last lien the line number 13

here are the include files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector> //for dynamic tables
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>//used for the function getch
#include "checkPassword.hpp"
#include "buffervoider.hpp"
#include "checktyping.hpp"
#include "extractline.hpp"
#include "getchoic.hpp"
#include "tableidentify.hpp"
```

the error here will be:

*|error: 'tableidentify' was not declared in this scope|*

but if i switch between #include "getchoic.hpp" and #include "tableidentify.hpp"
the error would be

*|error: 'getchoic' was not declared in this scope|*

also all my headers have include guards

so how to solve this problem ?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the number of includes. If there really is a limit, I've never encountered one. What you have here is a circular dependency problem.

Comment: `#include` statements should never be able to generate a "was not declared in this scope" error. Not even with circular dependencies. The error is on the #include itself, right? Not the stuff in the file you're #including?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You probably baby have circular includes: one file includes another, which includes the first.

Comment: yes i do. 
so? how can i fix this without affecting my circular includes because i need it

Comment: You have to break the cycle.

Comment: @shuzo You can not have circular includes.  Do a search on how to avoid it.

Comment: yeah i am having that in all my headers

Comment: @RSahu -missing include guards would produce redefinition errors. File disappearing means the include guards are doing their jobs.

Comment: @PeteBecker, it's possible the OP copied/pasted includes guards and didn't fix them.

Comment: all my headers dose not include any other header but in the source files of the function's they do include each other.is this what we call circular includes?

Comment: thank you @RSahu i found that the mistake was in my include guards. problem solved! now how can show that this problem was solved here?

Answer (score 0):

If those hpp files are yours, then remove the `#include` in one of them that includes the other so if `tableidentify.hpp` has `#includes getchoic` or vice versa, remove one of the includes to the other

Comment: all my headers dose not include any other header but in the source files of the function's they do include each other.is this a problem?

Comment: Yes they shouldnt include each other, or else that causes circular includes

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that some of those headers are user defined (i.e. you made them). If so, try combining all of the user-defined header include statements in another header, then including that.

Comment: and what about the .cpp files should i combine them also ? or i just include the super-header that i will creat in each one of them ?

Comment: 1 super-header. (By the way, did you down-vote my answer?)

Comment: no i didn't i was about to up vote if it works 
and here i am talking about the source files are they meant to be combined also ?

Comment: No, only thing that must be combined at lines #8-13